# Histogram residual not lining up with normality test

Tags: normality-assumption

[This](https://imgur.com/a/dTXM9a2) histogram residual looks less normal than [this](https://imgur.com/gqHQhVI) one (I think), yet the latter is giving me a lower p-value for the Jarque-Bera normality test. Specifically, the latter gives a p-value of 0.14 whilst the former gives a p-value of 0.56! Why are the results not lining up?

Comment: How many data points are plotted in each histogram?

Comment: @StephanKolassa My sample size is 100 (they both use the same data, only the second model incorporates a dummy variable).

Comment: I disagree. The one you call "more normal" is more skewed, so it is not obvious at all. A plot is usually more useful than a test, and a normal quantile plot is more use than a histogram. You're using Stata, so you can use `qnorm` directly. As you have small samples and neither test gives P-values that conventionally are a source of worry, the practical conclusion is the same.

Comment: @NickCox Alright that's actually what I suspected, but it wasn't obvious to me. Regarding p-values, I assumed there is a difference as I could reject the null more easily in the second instance (i.e. if I raise the significance level).
Edit: nvm I just read Stephan's answer

Comment: If you want to measure non-normality, the P-value is a lousy measure. Otherwise the reply to your comment depends on whether you want decisions from a test or indications. From your use of the Jarque-Bera test I guess you are some sort of economist. As I understand it, it hinges on using asymptotic values even for very small sample sizes! If you must use a test, Shapiro-Wilk or Doornik-Hansen seems better to me.

Comment: @NickCox Yes, this is for a uni econometrics assignment. To be honest, the only reason I even bothered with normality is because we needed to carry out (the necessary) diagnostic tests for the OLS assumptions. I initially decided against testing for autocorrelation and normality because it didn't seem pertinent, but then I read up on the Jarque-Bera and simply thought it wouldn't hurt to check it out. Of course, given the replies, I think it's best I just assume a large enough sample size and get on with the rest.

Comment: The real issue for you is what your teachers expect, and on that our advice is not much use. I suspect that most courses like yours expect immensely more formal testing than is part of my personal practice.

Comment: @NickCox You're right on that point. Though I think based on the replies, I will omit the test. Thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of bins (10) for few data points (100). Even perfectly normal distributions can yield "non-normal-looking" histograms in such cases. ([Compare this.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18747/4140))

Simulations are always good to get an idea of what we can reasonably expect under specific hypotheses - here, under the assumption of a normal distribution. For instance, let's simulate 100 normally distributed observations and plot them in a histogram with 10 bins, as in your case. Let's do this six times, just to get a feeling:

[image: histograms]

As you see, these histograms can look pretty non-normal indeed - all but one of them are even multimodal!

The important point is that these are all equally normal. After all, they were all generated with the same (normal) distribution. Thus, in particular, the shapes of your two histograms are *both* perfectly consistent with a normal distribution assumption.

And under the assumption of a normal distribution, the p value does not say anything about non-normality - under the null hypothesis, the p values are uniformly distributed between zero and one (see [the dance of the p values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1RqHrZQ8)). In particular, you cannot infer anything from one of your p values being larger than the other.

R code:

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
ss <- 1
nn <- 100

sims <- matrix(rnorm(6*nn,0,ss),nrow=6)

par(mfrow=c(2,3),las=1)
for ( ii in 1:6 ) hist(sims[ii,],xlim=range(sims),breaks=10,xlab="",ylab="",main="")
```

Comment: Besides these good points: The particular choice of cutoffs for bins can suprisingly strongly influence the appearance of the histogram (=you might just get unlucky that things by chance look more or less normal than they really are).

Comment: Ohhhh I see. In that case, I should probably just disregard any normality tests entirely then right? If it doesn't really add much substance, I'd better leave it out my analysis and assume a sufficiently large sample.

Comment: That is usually a good way forward. Depending on how many degrees of freedom you have, 100 data points are often quite enough for asymptotics to kick in.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for the advice